# mongoDB query $exists: false returns no documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a monboDB collection with ~500k documents:

```
> db.test.find().count()
491740
```

When I query record where `crawled` key exists:

```
> db.test.find({'crawled': {$exists: true}}).count()
6451
```

But when I query documents with no `crawled` key:

```
> db.test.find({'crawled': {$exists: false}}).count()
0
```

The results are similar with query `{$eq : null}`

I don't understand why result is 0, please explain me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3918) like the one you describe when you have a sparse index on that field. As the sparse index does not store information about documents which do not have the field, the query will never find any documents when using the sparse index.
According to the issue status this should be fixed but you may have an older version running. In that case you could of course either update or replace the sparse index with a regular one.
As workaround you could also calculate your desired result by counting all docs and then subtracting the one with `$exists: true`.